# Biztalk: Send and Receive multipart message in custom adapter

Tags: c#, biztalk, adapter

I am currently looking into using the BTS 2006 SDK "Submit" custom adapter to enable a unit test to invoke a test "wrapper" BTS orchestration. This "test" orchestration will in turn "call" or "start" the orchestration I wish to test.

I would prefer to use something like "submit" adapter rather than expose the "test" orchestration as a file drop or web service (as an example).

However I have hit a problem, the SDK "Submit" adapter works OK, but only appears to support single part messages even though IBaseMessage appears to offer (must offer) multipart message support.

If I customize the sample test orchestration and output a multipart message, the code runs OK, but the response received through the SDK submit adapter *only* contains the "body part" (note: The HAT activity shows all parts).

Does anyone know if it's possible to write a custom adapter (the submit adapter is isolated-host) that supports multi-part messages and where would be the best place to start??

Note: I have also looked at the BizTalkAdapterWizard (for BTS2006, VS2005), but my lack of experience with Adapters is making it difficult to see how I can make use of the generated code to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance using any pipeline on your response message that could be affecting the result? Not all pipeline components will preserve all the parts in a message (many components that create a new message forget [un]intentionally to copy non-body message parts).